# Unresolved constraint in bundle and missing requirement osgi.wiring.package = org.quartz)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))

Tags: osgi, constraints, bundle

I have a Web Application Client Bundle (WAB) with OSGi after a tutorial and I want to use packages from quartz scheduler for a specific task. I'm using also Maven and I put the following dependency:
        
        org.quartz-scheduler
        quartz
        2.2.1
        compile
        
        
        org.quartz-scheduler
        quartz-jobs
        2.2.1
        compile

I've checked in Maven repository and it seems to be everything ok, the packages/jars from the quartz jar are exported in the MANIFEST.MF. At compilation everything is fine but at the runtime I receive this error:

[#|2013-12-11T18:49:07.590+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=64;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle employee.identitymanagement.web_client [516]: Unable to resolve 516.0: missing requirement [516.0] osgi.wiring.package; (&(osgi.wiring.package=org.quartz)(version>=2.2.0)(!(version>=3.0.0)))
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundleRevision(Felix.java:3826)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1868)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:944)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1175)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:1153)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.processAllBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1146)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:456)
    at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:263)

And I'm not sure about the problem......If anyone can help me, I can give more details about it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a bundle into your runtime that exports the package `org.quartz`.

Comment: If my pom.xml contains dependency for Quartz 2.2.1 and the scope is compile then it not applied for the runtime too?

Comment: No. Maven is a build tool. It doesn't run your program.

Comment: Can you give me some details or how can I install a bundle in the runtime and export that package? I would be grateful if I knew the steps, thanks in advance!

Comment: I can't, because you didn't say anything about how you launched your program. However, you already know how to add one bundle: the one you made yourself. So do the same thing with the Quartz bundle.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a `feature.xml` file you most likely need to add a `<bundle></bundle>` to the feature in question.  Something similar to (and this assumes you're using apache commons-validator 1.4.1):

```
<feature name="foo" version="${project.version}-${build.number}">
    <bundle>mvn:org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/${apache.commons.lang.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-validator/commons-validator/${commons-validator.version}</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-beanutils/commons-beanutils/1.8.3</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-digester/commons-digester/1.8.1</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-logging/commons-logging/1.2</bundle>
    <bundle>mvn:commons-collections/commons-collections/3.2.1</bundle>
</feature>
```

Hope this helps.

FWIW, I would **strongly** discourage you from using the `<Export-Package>` element in the maven-bundle-plugin because overriding the default value of `*` for this element and adding your missing package will remove all the other packages added automatically by the `*` - which is almost assuredly NOT what you want.